# Поиск с учетом нескольких условий

Tags: java

Есть текстовые поля для номера, сотрудника, субъекта, улицы, дома, некоторые из них могут быть пустые, тогда надо искать по тем которые заполнены. Есть ли способ обойтись без сотни IF?

Comment: В чем ищите? Каким GUI фреймворков пользуетесь?

Comment: Сделайте методы для проверки строки каждого поля, возвращающие boolean. Ведь поля могут быть не только пустые. В поле номера, например, может быть некорректная длина или строка может содержать не цифры. То же самое у других полей есть свои ограничения.

Comment: Swing, с проверками сам справлюсь, главное соптимальное решение

Comment: Что за проблемы с if? Ну будет три строки на условие вместо одной. Да можно даже в одну замутить, применив всякую новомодную функцанальщину да предикаты. Как например в jpa criteria api

Answer (score 1):

Для начала как работает if(condition)

В качестве condition порой могут выступать конструкции длиной в несколько строк с использованием логических операндов &&, || и т.д

В случае использования && есть особенность - если хоть одно из условий будет false то машина не будет тратить свои ресурсы на вычисление остальных выражений, которые стоят после &&. 
Когда стоит такое условие

```
String x= null;
if(x!=null && true) {/*some stuff*/}
```

Тогда код в скобках не сработает, так как if сразу засчитает условие не выполненным наткнувшись на false в выражении x!=null

Для вас, чтобы обойтись без множественного if, нужно ставить проверки на null (или на пустые строки) в самом начале условия.

Также может использовать готовые библиотеки по типу Guava

```
Strings.isNullOrEmpty(String stringToCheck);
```

Которая сразу даст вам ответ на 2 главных вопроса.